# Storing hashed keys: CHAR(64) as datatype in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, mysql, migration, char, laravel

I'm fetching objects from a Webservice. Each object comes with a key with a format like:

> 300;VMMAAACLAQAAAACJ/1NFVkVSSU4AAIn/UzIgUExVUwAAif89WXIxLTAwMAAAh+DmCwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=9;2422359300;

I want to store this key hashed in a unique index. I figured I would hash it with **sha256** and use **CHAR(64)** for this, but would this be the "correct" way to store it?

Basically I would store the value of  `hash('sha256', $object->key)`

And also, how do I specify **CHAR** with a length of **64** in a Laravel 4 migration? This is definitely incorrect:

```
$table->char('hash_key', 64);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating this old question for completeness. As of 4.2.6, Laravel supports creating CHAR columns. In fact, the syntax in your question would now work well.

Answer (score 0):

Use $table->string('hash_key',64) to represent varchar(64)

[This is give you everything you need](http://laravel.com/docs/schema#adding-columns)

Comment: I am not interested in VARCHAR. CHAR is a fixed length.

Comment: Laravel does not support char, you would have to use varchar, and validate to input between the length needed.

Comment: Thanks, I settled for raw SQL.